# How can I use Javascript to find text inside <g:id>Text</g:id> and paste on first <g:mpn>DOLBLUU</g:mpn> tag

Tags: javascript, xml, replace, tags, getelementsbytagname

How can I use Javascript to find text inside 
`<g:id>Text</g:id>` and paste on first `<g:mpn>DOLBLUU</g:mpn>` tag

Example:
I want to loop through the XML document and find the `<g:id>` and get text and paste on the first `<g:mpn>` tag that it finds.

```
<item><g:id>DOLBLUU</g:id><g:mpn>DOLBLUU</g:mpn>
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are proposing to grab XML from a text area and parse it, then you should take a look at these Javascript XML-related libs.  In particular, you might want to check out XPATH, which allows you to reference any part of an XML document, according to a nutty-but-powerful query syntax.  If I understand what you're asking for, XPATH is probably it, but you'll see a few related items under "XML Technology" on the [XML Parser Javascript docs page](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp).

If I'm off the mark, perhaps you can provide samples of input and expected output with a little more explanation.

Comment: Hey BergBrains, thanks for the tip, and link. I will take a look!

Comment: Hey BergBrains. I was not able to resolve the problem with XPATH. Let me provide a better example so that you are able to understand exactly what I need. I have a xml document that is a Google product feed. In the XML there are two tags <g:id>DOLBLUU</g:id> and <g:mpn></g:mpn>. I have 1500 products and I don't want to manually copy the text inside the <g:id> tag and copy to <g:mpn> tag. So I was trying to get tips on how to accomplish this in Java or Javascript.. I hope this explains better. Thanks for you help!